# A basic doubt on Poisson

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

For a Poisson process the event "arrival at time $t$" = ${N(t+h)-N(t) =1}$ when $h->0$. Is this correct ? How ?

Comment: I would prefer ${N(t)-N(t-h) \ge 1}$ when $h \searrow 0$ because I would regard $N(t+h)-N(t)$ as the number of arrivals in the half-open interval $(t, t+h]$, but there would then be an issue with $t=0$

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The $n$th arrival happens at time $t$ if $N_t=n$ and $N_s\lt n$ for every $s\lt t$. Thus, the event that there is an arrival at time $t$ is 
$$
\bigcap_{k\geqslant1}[N_t-N_{t-1/k}=1]=\bigcap_{s\lt t}[N_t-N_s=1]=[N_t-N_{t-}=1].
$$
The proposition in the question is faulty because the paths of a Poisson process are càdlàg (in particular, continuous on the right), not càglàd, thus, even at a jump time $t$, $[N_s-N_t=1]$ is empty for every $s\gt t$, $s$ small enough.

Recall finally the definition of the Poisson process $(N_t)$ from the collection $(T_n)$ of jump times, which reads
$$
N_t=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\mathbf 1_{T_n\leqslant t}.
$$